# GDAL C# Bindings for VRT don't write a VRT file

Tags: gdal, c#, osgeo4w, gdalbuildvrt

I have previously asked this [question on stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55386597/gdal-c-sharp-wrapper-for-vrt-doesnt-write-a-vrt-file), and am now asking this more specialized audience.

I'm wondering why the GDAL C# library (v2.3.3) call to `Gdal.wrapper_GDALBuildVRT_names(...)` does not produce a physical destination VRT file.

When I issue the equivalent command in the OSGeo4W shell (to combine the `0000a013.gn1` and `0000b013.gn1` files), a VRT file is written to the supplied destination path (`C:\Temp\z7_x43_y43.vrt`):

```
gdalbuildvrt C:\Temp\z7_x43_y43.vrt F:\gnc\1\0000a013.gn1 F:\gnc\1\0000b013.gn1
```

However, when I issue the command in C#, **no VRT file** is written to the supplied destination path (I've made sure the folder exists and that the file isn't already there):

```
GdalConfiguration.ConfigureGdal();

var vrtFile = @"C:\Temp\z7_x43_y43.vrt";
var aeroFiles = new List<string>();
aeroFiles.Add(@"F:\gnc\1\0000a013.gn1");
aeroFiles.Add(@"F:\gnc\1\0000b013.gn1");

var vrtOptions = new GDALBuildVRTOptions(new [] { "-overwrite" });
var vrt = Gdal.wrapper_GDALBuildVRT_names(vrtFile, aeroFiles.ToArray(), vrtOptions, null, null);
```

The *.gn1 files are NITF, WGS84, degree unit files that work fine in other respects (e.g., the OSGeo4W command processes them perfectly).

The resulting `vrt` instance is correct - I can use it as a `Dataset` in other parts of my code, and can even cut PNG tiles from it doing something like this (`pngFile` and `translateOptions` are defined elsewhere):

```
Gdal.wrapper_GDALTranslate(pngFile, vrt, new GDALTranslateOptions(translateOptions.ToArray()), null, null);
```

But why is no VRT file ever written to disk? We have to supply a destination path (`vrtFile`), so doesn't that imply a destination file will be written?

Answer (score 0):

You can try

`var vrt = Gdal.wrapper_GDALBuildVRT_names(vrtFile, aeroFiles.ToArray(), vrtOptions, null, null);
vrt.FlushCache();` - it might can help you!